# How to fix android.support.v7.widget.SearchView RTL issue

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working with app in which user can able to change language at anytime. RTL changes throughout the app after selecting arabic language is working fine except the search view. search icon and close icon inside the search view doesn't changed to rtl.

xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_box_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:background="@drawable/search_box_shape"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_product" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In Fragment:

```
    activity!!.search_box_TV.gravity = Gravity.START

    val search_src_text = activity!!.search_box_TV.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) as EditText


    search_src_text.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    search_src_text.setGravity(Gravity.START or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
    search_src_text.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START
```

This is the image link before and after selecting the Arabic language,

---

**LTR** 
[image]

---

**RTL**
[image]

Problems:

- Search/Back icon and close icon are not on the right side after selecting the arabic language

Comment: Did you try this: 
`SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    search.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT)); `

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn I tried it but still issue is not fixed,Thank you for your kind attention

Comment: Have you tried `searchView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)`?

Comment: @azizbekian it will results in search view direction always in RTL!

Comment: Why always? Whenever you need to go back rom RTL to LTR then perform `searchView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @azizbekian now edit text inside the search view is changed to RTL but the search icon and close icon is not aligned according to RTL